# how to use google encrypted mail port in php mailer scripts

Tags: javascript, php, phpmailer

[I have my code which running perfectly but not **ENCRYPTED** so I want to know, How to use this method with Encryption. (my mail server is provided by Google)

```js
function sendMail($applicationID){
    $host = 'localhost'; 
    $user = 'username'; 
    $pass = 'password'; 
    $db = 'database';
    $conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db)  or die("Error ". mysqli_connect_error()). PHP_EOL;
    $distributor_details = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn,"select * from distributor where status = '1' and deleted IS NULL and id = '$applicationID' limit 0,1 "));
    if(isset($distributor_details['id'])){
        $state=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn,"select * from tbl_state where id='".$distributor_details['state']."' "));
        $country=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn,"select * from tbl_country where id='".$distributor_details['country']."' "));
        /*<tr>
                            <th height="25">Application ID:</th><td>'.distributorNumber($distributor_details['id']).'</td>
                        </tr>*/
        $message = '<html>
                <head>
                    <title>Triveni Almirah</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <h1>Dealer/Distributor Enquiry Details</h1>
                    <table cellspacing="0" style="border: 2px dashed #3c8dbc; width: 100%; height: auto;">
                        <tr style="background-color: #e0e0e0;">
                            <th height="25">Name:</th><td>'.stripslashes(strtoupper($distributor_details['fname'])).'</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th height="25">Email Id:</th><td>'.$distributor_details['email'].'</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color: #e0e0e0;">
                            <th height="25">Mobile:</th><td>'.$distributor_details['mobile'].'</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Address:</th><td>'.strtoupper($distributor_details['city']).'</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th height="25">Comments:</th><td>'.$distributor_details['comment'].'</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color: #e0e0e0;">
                            <th height="25">Posted Date:</th><td>'.date("d-m-Y",strtotime($distributor_details['post_date'])).'</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </body>
                </html>';
        $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0;\n"; 
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1;\n"; 
        $headers.='From:HIRDESH - VASHISHTHA <noreply@domain.com>' . "\r\n".PHP_EOL;
        //$headers.='CC: abcd48@gmail.com' . "\r\n".PHP_EOL;
        //$port = 587;
        //$auth = true;
        //echo $message; die;
        mail("data@domain.com","Distributorship Enquiry",$message,$headers);  
    }
    return true;
}
```

So now i want to remove logo of Question-mark on that Mails.

Comment: You may use gmail for your email, but this code is *not* using gmail for email; it's using your local mail server, which presumably is not set to use TLS for outbound SMTP. Read your mail server's documentation, or use PHPMailer (that you tagged this question with) to send directly through gmail, basing your code on the gmail example provided with it.

Comment: Hello Dear @Synchro now I did it by my self. Well Thanks a lot for your comment.

Comment: Sorry but you're talking rubbish. You are not sending via gmail, you're not encrypting anything, and that SMTPAuth param is just made up, doesn't exist. At the very least you should [read the docs on `mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Comment: okay thanks for advise. but that time my this code was running good

Comment: but now use multiple emails for receive this mail by **mail("data@domain.com","Distributorship Enquiry",$message,$headers,$SMTPAuth);**

Comment: I really don’t have anything to add. You’re not making any sense. When you use the mail function, there is no authentication, no encryption.

Comment: sorry for my last activity but now i need a encryption mail script as per my code.

Comment: Well, hard luck - you can't do it using the `mail()` function. You can using PHPMailer (that you tagged the question with), but you're not using that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a Answer of my Question that is mention below:

```
function sendMail($applicationID){
$host = 'localhost'; 
$user = 'username'; 
$pass = 'password'; 
$db = 'database';
$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db)  or die("Error ". mysqli_connect_error()). PHP_EOL;
$distributor_details = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn,"select * from distributor where status = '1' and deleted IS NULL and id = '$applicationID' limit 0,1 "));
if(isset($distributor_details['id'])){
    $state=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn,"select * from tbl_state where id='".$distributor_details['state']."' "));
    $country=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn,"select * from tbl_country where id='".$distributor_details['country']."' "));
    /*<tr>
                        <th height="25">Application ID:</th><td>'.distributorNumber($distributor_details['id']).'</td>
                    </tr>*/
    $message = '<html>
            <head>
                <title>Triveni Almirah</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Dealer/Distributor Enquiry Details</h1>
                <table cellspacing="0" style="border: 2px dashed #3c8dbc; width: 100%; height: auto;">
                    <tr style="background-color: #e0e0e0;">
                        <th height="25">Name:</th><td>'.stripslashes(strtoupper($distributor_details['fname'])).'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th height="25">Email Id:</th><td>'.$distributor_details['email'].'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="background-color: #e0e0e0;">
                        <th height="25">Mobile:</th><td>'.$distributor_details['mobile'].'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Address:</th><td>'.strtoupper($distributor_details['city']).'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th height="25">Comments:</th><td>'.$distributor_details['comment'].'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="background-color: #e0e0e0;">
                        <th height="25">Posted Date:</th><td>'.date("d-m-Y",strtotime($distributor_details['post_date'])).'</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </body>
            </html>';
    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0;\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1;\n"; 
    $headers.='From:HIRDESH - VASHISHTHA <noreply@domain.com>' . "\r\n".PHP_EOL;
    //$headers.='CC: abcd48@gmail.com' . "\r\n".PHP_EOL;
    $port = 587;
    $SMTPAuth = true;
    //echo $message; die;
    mail("data@domain.com","Distributorship Enquiry",$message,$headers,$SMTPAuth);  
}
return true;
```

}

Comment: It's only work for single email ID. and when we add multiple mail IDs then we got a warring : 
**PHP Warning:  mail(): Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header**